# How to resize Windows partition after conversion from RAID 1 to RAID 5?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, raid, raid5, ntfs

I'm using Fujitsu PRIMERGY RX200 S6 with RAID controller RAID Ctrl SAS 6G 5/6 512MB (D2616)

I've migrated RAID 1 (2 discs) to RAID 5 (4 discs) without any problems and on the fly without restarting the server. The new logical disk has now expanded in size and I see it from RAID manager software. From Windows Disk Manager it is still seen as old smaller size.

I thought I can resize the partition from Windows once migration to RAID 5 is finished but Windows doesn't see it. I didn't restart the server yet.

Is it possible to expand the disk size without destroying the data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do a rescan after a resize for Windows to see the new disk size.

In `diskmgmt.msc` click `Action` and select `Rescan Disks`

[image]

After that you can extend the partition as normal.